# findBySql in Yii2 not return expected resultset

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 and for my datatable i need data as categorized and limiting data per category, For achieving result for it i have used findBySql() but it's always return full result set from that model.

**It's working perfectly but i want to use it with model so i can have instance**

I just want following query give me yii\db\ActiveQuery instance with a given SQL statement.

Also i need instance so just result as simple array not needed.

I want result having max 10 rows per category id or id.

Here is sql

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT t.* , @currcount := IF( @currvalue = t.id, @currcount +1, 1 ) AS rank, @currvalue := t.id AS whatever
FROM test t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
) AS whatever';

$modelTest = Test::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Comment: A first glance I think it strange to get the models correcti from a select of this type .. but anyway .. Please explain what's the problem .. you have an error .? you have a wrong result? ... You have  no result ? have looked ad the content of $modelTest?

Comment: It gives me PDO exception for sql. But working fine in phpmyadmin. So just problem with Yii findBySql().

Comment: Obvous that can work in phpadmin .. your is a shell sql command .. but this not work as is in yii2 .. show the exact error  you have in yii2 please

Comment: using Database Access Objects  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-dao.md#executing-sql-queries-

Answer (score 0):

Please using Database Access Object
Example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT t.* , @currcount := IF( @currvalue = t.id, @currcount +1, 1 ) AS rank, @currvalue := t.id AS whatever
FROM test t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
) AS whatever';

$data= Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
            ->queryAll();
```

Comment: It gives wrong rank, every row has rank 1, instead adding +1